# How to implement ngxsOnChanges in a component

Tags: ngxs

I have two properties in state model, and I need an event on each one of them separately, but when both change at the same time I receive two events and I need only one something like `ngxsOnChanges`

Comment: You might find these helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004144/2436787 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66421744/2436787

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector to combine both of them and then you will be able to subscribe to this selector and use a `debounce`.

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple selectors using the `@Selector` decorator, but take care of the `injectContainerState` selector option, which is disabled by default in NGXS v4 (It's better to set it to `false` if you're using NGXS v3.x)

Then, you can subscribe to the new selector in your component.

```
 @Selector([ZooState, PreferencesState])
 static firstLocalPanda(state: string[], preferencesState: PreferencesStateModel) {
   return state.find(
     s => s.indexOf('panda') > -1 && s.indexOf(preferencesState.location)
   );
 }

 @Selector([ZooState.firstLocalPanda])
 static happyLocalPanda(panda: string) {
   return 'happy ' + panda;
 }
```

To learn more about joining selectors:
https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#joining-selectors